# Have thumbnails of remaining videos showing underneath playing video

Tags: php, html

What I am trying to do is something like below:

[image]

The buttons at the side can be ignored. So the idea is that the big square is the main video playing and the little ones underneath will be the thumbnails of the remaining videos. The main video playing is randomly picked when the site is loaded and then the ones that are not playing, the thumbnails will be shown underneath. I am doing this like so:

```
    <?php
        try {
            $items = array();

        $stmt = $dbconn->query('SELECT videoid, video, thumbnail, videotitle, tags, editedby FROM videos ORDER BY RAND()');
        while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
            $video = $row['video'];
            $videoThumbnail = $row['thumbnail'];
            $videoTitle = $row['videotitle'];
            echo $video;
            array_push($items, $video);
                $video = $row['video'];

                }
                
                shuffle($items);
                
                $restVideos = array();

                foreach($items as $key => $videoArray) {
                if($key === 0) continue;

                array_push($restVideos, $videoArray);
                
            }
            

        }catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
                ?>

<video id=v controls loop align="right"> 

    <source src="users/videos/<?php echo $items[0];?>" type="video/mp4">
</video> 


<?php

    $thumbnails = array();
    $videoTitles = array();
    
    foreach($restVideos as $videoThumbnail) {
        try {
        $stmt = $dbconn->query("SELECT thumbnail, videoTitle FROM videos WHERE video = '$videoThumbnail'");
        while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
        $thumbnail = $row['thumbnail'];
        array_push($thumbnails, $thumbnail);
    }
    
        }catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        
} 

    foreach($thumbnails as $nonPlaying) {
?>

<img src=<?php echo $nonPlaying ?> id="thumbnails" width="200" height="100">

<?php } ?>
```

what is happening at the moment is below:

[image]

Each image is just stacking up against each other how can I change it so this is not the case?

Also is there a more efficient way of doing this than what I am currently doing?

Edit:

```
$thumbnails = array();
     $videoTitles = array();
     $test = 700;
     echo "<div>";
     foreach($restVideos as $rVideo) {
         $test = 200 + $test;
             ?>
             <img src=<?php echo $videoMap[$rVideo]['thumbnail'] ?> id="thumbnails" width="200" height="100" style= "left: <?php echo $test?>px">
             <?php    
             echo "</div>";

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You not required to two query two times to db .
   Use key value and store the entire video. While printing thumbnail based on the key (unique id ex. videoid). You can retrieve the content when you print the thumbnail list and can avoid querying again in a loop.
   Ref to code snipp

   ```
     <?php
            try {
                $items = array();

            $stmt = $dbconn->query('SELECT videoid, video, thumbnail, videotitle, tags, editedby FROM videos ORDER BY RAND()');
            while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
                $video = $row['video'];
                $videoMap[$row['videoid']] = $row;
                $videoThumbnail = $row['thumbnail'];
                $videoTitle = $row['videotitle'];
                if (count($items) == 0) echo $video;
                    array_push($items, $row['videoid']);
                    $video = $row['video'];

            }

                    shuffle($items);

                    $restVideos = array();

                    foreach($items as $key => $videoArray) {
                    if($key === 0) continue;

                    array_push($restVideos, $videoArray);

                }


            }catch(PDOException $e) {
                    echo $e->getMessage();
                }
                    ?>

    <video id=v controls loop align="right"> 

        <source src="users/videos/<?php echo $videoMap[$items[0]]['video'];?>" type="video/mp4">
    </video> 


    <?php

        $thumbnails = array();
        $videoTitles = array();
        echo "<div>";
        foreach($restVideos as $rVideo) {
                ?>
                <img src=<?php echo $videoMap[$rVideo]['thumbnail'] ?> id="thumbnails" width="200" height="100">
                <?php    
                }
                echo "</div>";

    } 
                ?>
   ```
2. Use a div tag and print the image thumbnails.

Comment: That's a lot cleaner, thank you, however, when the thumbnail images are printed, they are still all just on top of each other?

Comment: Can I ask about this line as well:   $videoMap[$row['videoid']] = $row; why is it like that not $videoMap = $row['videoid']; ?

Comment: You need to have it as key value pair . $videoMap[$row['videoid']] = $row; ex. Emp[1110] = "abc"; Emp[3323] = "xyz"; For Images printed on top, share the CSS and screen shot as well.

Comment: Ah, okay thank you. And for images I've edited to show what I've done now so the images aren't stacked on top of each other but I'm guessing there's surely a better way of doing it?

Comment: This is the optimized way, you are sending only one db call . Not multiple

Comment: Right okay, thanks for the help with this